# Caching in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-delivery

I need caching in my Azure Devops Pipeline

I have extensively used many CI/CD tools with terraform, I have found that keeping state between jobs is a mission (reinitializing backends, switching woprkspaces, etc) and think that by caching the .terraform folder I do not need to do this between jobs (this works perfectly in gitlabs CI/CD tool)

I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
cache:
    path: .terraform

job:
    use_cache: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Pipeline caching will be available soon. You can follow its progress on this [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/pull/113)